# A method that takes both NSArray and NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I want to create a method that can take an `NSMutableArray` or an `NSArray` object.

I think I can just use (id) as the parameter type... or convert the `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` before passing. However I'm not really happy with these solutions.

In other languages I might pass an `IList` or some shared object that they both inherit from...

I need to enumerate through the array in my method.

What is the way people would typically do this in objective c?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take `NSArray`. `NSMutableArray` derives from `NSArray`, so as long as you're only using the `NSArray` members (such as read-only enumeration), you'll be safe.

Relevant documentation (from Apple's developer site):

- [NSMutableArray class reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [NSArray class reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray)

Comment: indeed, that's what I would do in fact

Comment: This is an actual thing called the Liskov substitution principle — any place you can use a type, you should be able to use one of its subtypes. So any function taking an NSObject (such as the `retain` and `release` methods) can take an NSString, a function taking an NSString can take an NSMutableString, and so on. In fact, the NSArrays you use are *never* direct instances of NSArray — they're actually instances of a private subclass, and it "just works" because of the substitution principle.

Answer (score 5):

Since `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`, just have your method take an `NSArray` parameter. That way, it will take anything that is or is a subclass of `NSArray`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSArray*` -- `NSMutableArray` inherits from it and you can iterate both as if they were `NSArray`s.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with NSArray as the parameter because I prefer to use immutable objects wherever possible (looser coupling), and then use the `-mutableCopy` method when required to send them to an to a function that needs to modify the array.